# `this` is undefined when used in a Destructuring Parameter function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this function inside my class which has Destructuring parameters

```
export default class MainCtrl {

    constructor(mainService ) {
        'ngInject';

        this.mainService = mainService;
    }

    $onInit() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.search);
    }

    search({ coords }) {
        console.log(this); // shows undefined
        this.mainService.search(coords);
    }
}
```

Now when im using this.mainService it says this is always undefined. How to pass the this instance on this kind of function?

Comment: try console.log(this) to debug

Comment: @MonicaAcha shows undefined

Comment: how is this a duplicate question JLRIshe? please explain

Comment: @SecretCoder You're passing `this.functionName` as a callback. The problem has nothing to do with destructuring. Check out the links above.

Comment: @JLRishe how can I use the this then if the code structure is like that?

Comment: @SecretCoder Have a look at the answers to those questions.

Comment: @JLRishe thanks. got it already. i use .bind()